# Not able to login from node Realm SDK

Tags: node.js, mongodb, realm

I have created an App service tried to connect to it using the electron example but while doing await realmApp.logIn(Realm.Credentials.anonymous()) getting an error.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yblEu.png)
I have enabled anonymous login have added user roles and also configured my local IP

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text* in the question, not links and images; if the links break, it would invalidate the question.  See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Also. images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)